# CSS Safari transition with transform and width not working

Tags: css, safari, width, transform, transition

```
.items { 
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;

  width: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.items.animation {
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
}
```

I use transition to animate transform and width in the same time.
It works well in other browsers but not in safari.

When the animation(transition) finished, get the element value correctly. But 'width' and 'transform' doesnt work by transition (for example 1sec).
Safari doesnt calculate the width value by transition in my opinion. Thats why this transfrom translate 50% calculate with the origin value of width...

I wouldnt like to create one more element as much as possible.
Has anyone idea to figure it?

Example is here:

***https://codepen.io/jh-ko/pen/xxdbzga***

please test and compare in safari and (chrome/firefox etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is working as of iOS 15.5 as far as I can tell.